# Parameterize a curve given by the intersection of two regular surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

My differential geometry course is using Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*. I am struggling with the following homework problem.

**I have already shown:**
Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ is a map described by $F(x,y,z) = (f(x,y,z),g(x,y,z))$ with $F(x_0,y_0,z_0) = (0,0)$. Suppose $u = \nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $v = \nabla g(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ are not parallel in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $w = u \wedge v$. Let $G:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a map given by $G(x,y,z) = (f(x,y,z),g(x,y,z),w \cdot (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0))$. Show that $dG_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}$ is invertible.

**I am struggling with the followup question(s):**
By the inverse function theorem, in a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $(0,0,0)$, such that $G|_U$ is a bijection from $U$ to $V$, and $G^{-1}$ is continuous and differentiable from $V$ to $U$. Use $G^{-1}$ to parameterize ${(x,y,z):f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z)=0}$ near $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. You may assume $G^{-1}(x,y,z) = (\alpha (x,y,z), \beta(x,y,z), \gamma(x,y,z))$.

I have tried, however so far I only have that, when mapped to $V$, the curve takes the form of a vertical line through the origin. Would it then be parameterized as $X = (0,0,\omega(x,y,z))$, for some function $\omega$?

The final question asks to show that in the above setting, $\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0) \wedge \nabla g(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a tangent vector to the curve ${(x,y,z):f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z)=0}$ at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

I feel that it is quite easy to say that as both gradients are perpendicular to the curve, and therefore parallel to some normal vector, that the wedge of them is parallel to the tangent vector at that point. However, I do not think this is a rigorous answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially for the second question. Thank you.